# How to store unlimited data in list?

Tags: jsf, arraylist, rerender

I want to make a form in which user can enter the unlimited data and it gets stored in bean with the help of arraylist.
[a busy cat http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/917/offerride.png](http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/917/offerride.png)
As in the image when user click on the click button then content of its near text box must be stored in the arraylist and it must be rerendered and become blank again.
I tried to use this code.

```
<td>
 <h:inputText label="Source" id="offerridepickuppts" value="#{OfferRideBacking.pickUpAdd}"/>
 <h:commandButton value="Click" action="index">
  <f:actionListener rendered="offerridepickuppoints,some" />
 </h:commandButton>
</td>
```

pickupAdd is another String variable in which button will be clicked its setter method will add the content in arraylist.
But it seems that it is not getting stored into the list. So how can I achieve this without using ajax and all that stuffs.
Thanks

Comment: You want something similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15104050/1065197)?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I was just looking at that topic...