# adding duplicate components to a JSF panel grid

Tags: jsf, components, containers

I am reasonably new to Java/JSF development (previously Mainframe legacy) so I am hoping someone will be able to let me know if what I am about to ask is possible and how to do it. Or at least point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to create a portlet where I can add the same component over and over again up to a maximum of 30 times. Eventually the data behind these components will be different in each one but from the same database. What I've done so far is create a container component and a button which calls a method to add something to the container. Like as follows:

```
<h:body>
      <h:form>
        <ice:panelGrid binding="#{simpleBean.containerComponent}"/>
        <br/>
        <ice:commandButton  value="add new section" action="#{simpleBean.addComponent}" />
       </h:form>
</h:body>
```

What I'm struggling with is the backing bean to create and render the component. At the minute I am just trying to create anything that repeats. The final code will be more complex than this.

```
private HtmlPanelGrid containerComponent;
private int i = 1;

public void addComponent() {

UIColumn uiColumn = new UIColumn();
uiColumn.setId("UIColumn_"+i);

HtmlOutputText htmlOutputText = new HtmlOutputText();
htmlOutputText.setId("HtmlOutputText_"+i);
htmlOutputText.setValue("HtmlOutputText_1_Value");

HtmlInputText htmlInputText = new HtmlInputText();
htmlInputText.setId("HtmlInputText_"+i);
htmlInputText.setValue("HtmlInputText_1_Value");

uiColumn.getChildren().add(htmlOutputText);
uiColumn.getChildren().add(htmlInputText);

if (containerComponent == null) {
    containerComponent = new HtmlPanelGrid();
}

containerComponent.getChildren().add(uiColumn);

i++;
}
```

I can get the code to render something the first time the button is clicked but nothing happens subsequently. In an ideal world I'd get 30 of the same component displayed on the screen.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thank you in advance.

Chris

Comment: What is the scope of your bean?

Comment: Are you looking something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104287/1065197)?

Comment: I think so. I'll take a look and see if it helps. What I basically  want to do is to add the same component (with different id) again and again. I've gathered I need to change the id because when I dont I get a component already exists error.