# Display a list in a JSF view with ability to add elements to it

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need to be able to dynamically show elements of an `ArrayList` in a JSF view. I want to view all the items of a list and then later on have a possibility of adding other elements to that list by using a commandButton so that the JSF view could be updated.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

I have a JSF page and I have a `Message` class and a `Conversation` class which holds a list of messages. I want to show several conversation objects and their respective messages in a JSF page.

Comment: did you try `<ui:repeat>`

Comment: More specifically, did you try *anything*? If yes, show us your attempts and we'll correct you.

Comment: [Here's a sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104287/1065197) using PrimeFaces. If you want to do it using plain JSF, just change `<p:commandButton>` per `<h:commandButton>`, remove the `update` attribute from the commandButton and add `<f:ajax render="pnlItems" />` (it will behave the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is absolutely possible (and easy to develop). Just view the items of the `ArrayList` with a `h:dataTable` component. If you add an `h:commandButton` component with an action that adds an item to this list, the data table is updated automatically in the browser as the page is re-rendered.